# Deserializing JSON with Jackson for polymorphic classes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am attempting to deserialize JSON which can be either a GroupRule or AttributeRule:

```
AbstractRule
  GroupRule
  AttributeRule
```

I want my models/entities/POJOs to be generic as I also use the same classes in other projects with Snakeyaml or other serialization providers.

Having said that, I stumbled across this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

which in the article, it indicates I could do:

```
{ // Using fully-qualified path
    "@class" : "com.fasterxml.beans.EmployeeImpl", ...
  }
```

However, when I do that, I am getting:

```
Cannot construct instance of `com.walterjwhite.email.organization.api.configuration.rule.AbstractRule` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (FileInputStream); line: 4, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.walterjwhite.email.organization.api.configuration.rule.EmailMatcherRule["rule"])
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
```

My configuration is this:

```
 {
    "name": "default",
    "ordering": "1",
    "rule": {
        "@class": "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.api.configuration.rule.GroupRule",
        "criteriaType": "Should",
        "rules": [
            {"@class": "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.api.configuration.rule.AttributeRule",
            "emailMessageField": "Subject",
            "values": ["default"]
            }
        ]
    },
    "matchType": "ContainsIgnoreCase",
    "actionClassNames": [
        "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.plugins.count.CountAction",
        "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.plugins.index.IndexAction",
        "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.plugins.reply.MoveAction"
    ]
}
```

On the Java side of things, I am doing this generally:

```
mapper.readValue(inputStream, entityType);
```

Now, the entityType in this case is EmailMatcherRule which inside it has a rule field which can either be attribute or group.  Inputstream is just the fileInputStream I am passing in ...

I am using Jackson 2.10.1.  I also converted the above JSON from YAML which was working fine via Snakeyaml.  Note that it automatically embeds the classes into the YAML, so this was a non-issue with it.

Is my JSON correct - according to the documentation, I should be able to add the @class attribute to specify the class I want to use, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this:

```
objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(objectMapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator());
```

Now, my JSON looks like this (NOTE: this is a different test entity, but you get the idea):

```
{
"name": "default",
"ordering": "1",
"rule": [
    "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.api.configuration.rule.GroupRule",
    {
        "criteriaType": "Should",
        "rules": ["java.util.HashSet",[[
            "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.api.configuration.rule.AttributeRule",
            {
                "emailMessageField": ["com.walterjwhite.email.organization.api.configuration.rule.EmailMessageField", "Subject"],
                "values": ["java.util.HashSet", [
                    "default"
                ]],
                "matchType": ["com.walterjwhite.email.organization.api.configuration.rule.MatchType","ContainsIgnoreCase"]
            }]]
        ]
    }
],
"actionClassNames": ["java.util.ArrayList",[
    "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.plugins.count.CountAction",
    "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.plugins.index.IndexAction",
    "com.walterjwhite.email.organization.plugins.reply.MoveAction"
    ]
]
```

}

So, the reference documentation I saw with @class seems inaccurate.  I am not really happy about adding all this extra information especially when some of it isn't needed - java.util.ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below and it worked without any configuration. Not sure if thats what you want to achieve:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String groupRuleStr = "{\"parentId\":\"parent\",\"groupId\":\"group\"}";
    String attributeRuleStr = "{\"parentId\":\"parent\",\"attributeId\":\"attribute\"}";

    GroupRule groupRule = mapper.readValue(groupRuleStr, GroupRule.class);
    AttributeRule attributeRule = mapper.readValue(attributeRuleStr, AttributeRule.class);

    System.out.println(groupRule.groupId);
    System.out.println(attributeRule.attributeId);

}

static abstract class AbstractRule {
    public String parentId = "parent";
}

static class GroupRule extends AbstractRule {
    public String groupId = "group";
}

static class AttributeRule extends AbstractRule {
    public String attributeId = "attribute";
}
```

Comment: Yes, so I want this to be as generic as possible.  While I can certainly do that, I won't be iterating through each nested object.  I am instead only reading the top-level object and expecting that I can declare the child types and let it automatically instantiate it correctly from that (like snakeyaml does).